# Javascrip: How do i close a bootstrap modal in using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a modal that pops out after sometime not when i click on a button, but i would like to permently close the modal and set it in a localstorage if that particular user does not want to see the modal again.

This is the code that i have written to try that

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        const showModal = localStorage.getItem("modal") === null;
        $(".modal").toggleClass("d-none")
        $(".modal_close").on("click",function() {
            localStorage.setItem("modal","seen");
            $(this).closest(".modal").addClass("d-none")
        });
    })    
</script>
```

the modal

```
 <div class="modal  fade" style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.548);" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog  modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content animate-grad text-white">
            <div class="modal-header text-center">
                <h5 class="modal-title " style="text-align: center;" id="exampleModalLabel"><strong>{{follow_us.title}}</strong></h5>
                <p style="border-top: 1px solid white;"></p>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            {% if follow_us.content %}
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>{{ follow_us.content }}</p>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
            <div class="d-flex text-white">
                
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer w-100">
               
                <a  style="cursor: none;" class="modal_close close"> Do not show this again.</a>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

i want to permanently close the modal when a clicks on the <kbd>Do not show this again</kbd> button. How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this.

> **Note**: `localStorage` does not work in the "code snippet" so you have to test the code locally.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    if( !localStorage.getItem("modal-seen") ){
        setTimeout(() => $('#exampleModal').modal('show'), 1000); // wait a sec before showing modal
        $('.modal_close').click(function(){
            localStorage.setItem("modal-seen", true);
            $('#exampleModal').modal('hide');
        })
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="modal fade" style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.548);" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog  modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content animate-grad text-white">
            <div class="modal-header text-center">
                <h5 class="modal-title " style="text-align: center;" id="exampleModalLabel"><strong>{{follow_us.title}}</strong></h5>
                <p style="border-top: 1px solid white;"></p>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            {% if follow_us.content %}
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>{{ follow_us.content }}</p>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
            <div class="d-flex text-white">
                
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer w-100">
                <a  style="cursor: none;" class="modal_close close"> Do not show this again.</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i can see in the localstorage that it is been saved but when i refresh it still pops out? is there something i might be missing. I tried changing the `<a>` to `<button>` but it still the same thing

Comment: @DestinyFranks it works perfectly. Check it out here https://achlamydeous-adapti.000webhostapp.com/modal.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you can change it like this

```
const showModal = localStorage.getItem("modal") === null;
$(".modal").modal("show")
$(".modal_close").on("click",function() {
   localStorage.setItem("modal","seen")
   $(this).closest(".modal").modal('hide')
});
```

but I wonder if you could change the `id` of modal